# how to get specific column's value after using filter

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, tablerowsorter

I have used TableRowsorter to filter some rows out from myJtable. Is there a way I can take all the values from a column and store it in arraylist after the filter from the Jtable.

Comment: `JTable#getValueAt` - you'll need to do it for each row and column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, something like this...

```
// Apply filter...
int col = ...; // Column you're interested in
List values = new ArrayList(table.getRowCount());
for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
    values.add(table.getValueAt(row, col));
}
```

will work.

Because `JTable` is a representation of the filtered (and sorted) data, you can just walk through it to get the values it's presenting